# Importing CSV into Mysql Python 3.x

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I'm trying to import a csv file into mysql using python for practice. I believe I've downloaded the right libraries. Every time I run my code I get the error:

**mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)' at line 1**

I can't figure out why this won't work and all answers seem to be using mysqldb, which doesn't support python 3.x.

My code:

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='comeonin', host='127.0.0.1', database='boxresults')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
csv_data = pd.read_csv('Betting/boxresults3.csv')

for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table1(Week, Day, Date, Winner, Loser, PtsW, PtsL, YdsW, TOW, YdsL, TOL) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s, %s)", row)


cursor.close() 
cnx.close()
```

New Code:

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='comeonin', host='127.0.0.1', database='boxresults')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
csv_data = pd.read_csv('Betting/boxresults3.csv') 

for row in csv_data.iterrows():
    list = row[1].values
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table1(Week, Day, Date, Winner, Loser, PtsW, PtsL, YdsW, TOW, YdsL, TOL) VALUES('%d','%s','%s','%s','%s','%d','%d','%d','%d','%d', '%d')" % tuple(list))

cursor.close() 
cnx.close()
```

Comment: print `row` and see what you have in row. `execute()` expects tuple with 11 elements.

Comment: when I print row I get 11 different column names, but I don't think it is a tuple. It's printing them 1 by 1.

Comment: Why the overhead of pandas? Csv module would nicely do. And if using, pandas consider its [to_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) to bulk append in one call. Even still MySQL has the [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) command for text files.

Comment: mysqldb has a Python 3 version: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient --- works exactly the same. Also, not sure if this is a mysql.connector thing (which is CONSIDERABLY slower by the way), but does %d even work? mysqldb only allows %s, regardless of type... also, row needs to be strictly a tuple (again, mysqldb, not sure but worth mentioning...) Also, don't use quotation marks around your params like suggested below... let me know if you still need help and I'll sort you out...

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong `row`.

```
 for row in csv_data
```

gives you column name in `row`

To get row you need `iterrows()`

```
 for row in csv_data.iterrows():
```

But this `row` has not only `values` but other information. You values are in `row[1]` but as `Series` object so you need `values` to get values as list

```
 for row in csv_data.iterrows():
     print( row[1].values )
```

---

Full working example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], columns=['a','b','c'])

print(df)

for row in df.iterrows():
    print('type:', type(row[1]))
    print('values:', row[1].values)
```

Results:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
type: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
values: [1 2 3]
type: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
values: [4 5 6]
```

Comment: That helps me break up each row. But the list is still not able to be inputted into mysql. I'm getting the same error. Does this list not input correctly as 11 values for the expectation of 11 values in the execute?

Comment: It works if I use quotation marks `('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')`

Comment: I had to make some tweaks to my code. I got it to run with no error, but the table is not populating with anything. I've added my new code above.

Comment: You need `cnx.commit()` to send data to database.